# ValueError: invalid literal for init() with base 10 - psychopy gamma correction PR650

Tags: python-2.7, psychopy

I am attempting to gamma correct my screen and do a chromatic calibration using a PR650, Psychopy (latest version) and Mac OSx with Mavericks.

When running the gamma calibration without the PR650 attached I don't get any errors, but with it attached the psychopy freezes after one measurement and the below error is given. I am new to psychopy and so any help would be great!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PsychoPy2.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/psychopy/monitors/MonitorCenter.py", line 729, in onCalibGammaBtn
    stimSize=stimSize, monitor=self.currentMon)
  File "/Applications/PsychoPy2.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/psychopy/monitors/calibTools.py", line 851, in getLumSeries
actualLum = photometer.getLum()
  File "/Applications/PsychoPy2.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/psychopy/hardware/pr.py", line 156, in getLum
    self.measure()
  File "/Applications/PsychoPy2.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/psychopy/hardware/pr.py", line 443, in measure
    self.lastColorTemp = int(self.getLastColorTemp()[3])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '003208.'
```

Answer (score 0):

That's strange. The error literally is caused by the fact that PsychoPy is trying to interpret the string '003208.' as an integer and Python is confused by the '.' in the string.

The string comes from the serial port when the PR650 was sent the command to report the temperature in Kelvin. I'm not sure why that's recently become an issue (maybe your PR650 is returning colour temperature as a decimal whereas mine returned an integer?

Anyway, the fix is to edit the file
  /Applications/PsychoPy2.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/psychopy/hardware/pr.py
so that line 443 says:

`self.lastColorTemp = int(float(self.getLastColorTemp()[3]))`

That way the string '003208.' get converted to a float first 3208.0 and **then** to an integer 3208 (kelvin)